# Unexpected NaN value for virtualView.Height in GetDesiredSizeFromHandler of Maui app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, maui

When I run my Maui app it fails at `ViewHandlerExtensions` in the namespace `Microsoft.Maui`. Previously when I connect my Android and select the device from Android Local Devices and run the debugger it worked.

Last night, it loaded a few times. But since then it has been erroring in this file. Crazy thing is that this file is NOT in my code base. The location of this file is:
`C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\f44e4109387c12ac95457c136b1a9d98770c4d8a0d4e46d8292e17ac198b041e\ViewHandlerExtensions.Android.cs`

The error occurs in the `GetDesiredSizeFromHandler` method.

```
// Create a spec to handle the native measure
var widthSpec = Context.CreateMeasureSpec(widthConstraint, virtualView.Width, virtualView.MaximumWidth);
var heightSpec = Context.CreateMeasureSpec(heightConstraint, virtualView.Height, virtualView.MaximumHeight);

platformView.Measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
```

The error is that the `virtualView.Height` is `NaN` when I inspect it. The exception says:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

here is the call stack:

```
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.monodroid_debugger_unhandled_exception C#
    0x1A in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:12,5 C#
    0x1F in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPI_L at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:67,26   C#
    0xB in System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException    C#
    0x9 in System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.DataTemplate,System.Collections.Generic.List<DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView.Android.RendererContainer>>.FindValue  C#
    0x2 in System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.DataTemplate,System.Collections.Generic.List<DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView.Android.RendererContainer>>.TryGetValue    C#
    0x13 in DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView.Android.ViewProvider.RequestViewByIndex  C#
    0x2 in DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView.Android.ViewProvider.GetViewByIndex   C#
    0x9 in Com.Devexpress.Dxlistview.Core.IDXListItemViewProviderInvoker.n_GetViewByIndex_I C#
    0x9 in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPI_L at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:66,5 C#
    0x39 in Java.Interop.NativeMethods.java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_void_method_a    C#
    0x79 in Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:12320,4  C#
    0x21 in Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualVoidMethod at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:46,5    C#
    0x3C in Android.Views.View.Measure at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net6.0/android-31/mcw/Android.Views.View.cs:17585,5   C#
>   0x5D in Microsoft.Maui.ViewHandlerExtensions.GetDesiredSizeFromHandler at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\f44e4109387c12ac95457c136b1a9d98770c4d8a0d4e46d8292e17ac198b041e\ViewHandlerExtensions.Android.cs:91,4  C#
    0x3 in Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler<DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView.DXCollectionView,Com.Devexpress.Dxlistview.DXListViewNative>.GetDesiredSize at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\d3ec223c6cb20ec4aede8c74299f4186e4e1eebe53ac652f30e1ebdea893515b\ViewHandlerOfT.Android.cs:18,4  C#
    0x41 in Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.LayoutExtensions.ComputeDesiredSize at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\2ae5b231c725ac3aac7255c54f0005b7d02c4b5f44d7482e234aaea394223493\LayoutExtensions.cs:26,4   C#
    0x4 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.MeasureOverride at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\acee58e3160c6638c809b2507259264e7aa5efe08e2a1b7922848fd5c6386e84\VisualElement.Impl.cs:149,4  C#
    0x3 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IView.Measure at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\acee58e3160c6638c809b2507259264e7aa5efe08e2a1b7922848fd5c6386e84\VisualElement.Impl.cs:142,4 C#
    0x7D in Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.GridLayoutManager.GridStructure.MeasureCells at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\0515e8ac5b00db0812fb990877b7cc5e707a9b39ef3c1a561b499e1339d5708f\GridLayoutManager.cs:371,7    C#
    0x1C8 in Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.GridLayoutManager.GridStructure..ctor at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\0515e8ac5b00db0812fb990877b7cc5e707a9b39ef3c1a561b499e1339d5708f\GridLayoutManager.cs:149,5  C#
    0x9 in Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.GridLayoutManager.Measure at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\0515e8ac5b00db0812fb990877b7cc5e707a9b39ef3c1a561b499e1339d5708f\GridLayoutManager.cs:22,4 C#
    0x8 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Layout.CrossPlatformMeasure at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\91a061fa0393bff02b6fb4e2c2b723bc80d35b4c7d6430fbaa7df5e5d793216a\Layout.cs:269,4    C#
    0x49 in Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutViewGroup.OnMeasure at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\5e7bb4cb58960e36127ca053b2d17d075643d7b9cd5f78d3fcc5aaf7338dd01d\LayoutViewGroup.cs:64,4 C#
    0xA in Android.Views.View.n_OnMeasure_II at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net6.0/android-31/mcw/Android.Views.View.cs:18806,4 C#
    0xB in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPII_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:154,5   C#
    0x39 in Java.Interop.NativeMethods.java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_void_method_a    C#
    0x79 in Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:12320,4  C#
    0x21 in Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualVoidMethod at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:46,5    C#
    0x3C in Android.Views.View.Measure at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net6.0/android-31/mcw/Android.Views.View.cs:17585,5   C#
    0x5D in Microsoft.Maui.ViewHandlerExtensions.GetDesiredSizeFromHandler at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\f44e4109387c12ac95457c136b1a9d98770c4d8a0d4e46d8292e17ac198b041e\ViewHandlerExtensions.Android.cs:91,4  C#
    0x3 in Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler<Microsoft.Maui.ILayout,Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutViewGroup>.GetDesiredSize at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\d3ec223c6cb20ec4aede8c74299f4186e4e1eebe53ac652f30e1ebdea893515b\ViewHandlerOfT.Android.cs:18,4  C#
    0x41 in Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.LayoutExtensions.ComputeDesiredSize at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\2ae5b231c725ac3aac7255c54f0005b7d02c4b5f44d7482e234aaea394223493\LayoutExtensions.cs:26,4   C#
    0x4 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.MeasureOverride at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\acee58e3160c6638c809b2507259264e7aa5efe08e2a1b7922848fd5c6386e84\VisualElement.Impl.cs:149,4  C#
    0x3 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IView.Measure at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\acee58e3160c6638c809b2507259264e7aa5efe08e2a1b7922848fd5c6386e84\VisualElement.Impl.cs:142,4 C#
    0x54 in Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.VerticalStackLayoutManager.Measure at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\b920329f24b23f8631e710b873200c1fcc915dc2c0abc0ac5c4ea6ebb50aa32c\VerticalStackLayoutManager.cs:29,5  C#
    0x8 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.StackLayoutManager.Measure at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\aaa23955116bd41221b3c7a114acb87dac47a91483582d21a8570b362d5f1d8a\StackLayoutManager.cs:41,4  C#
    0x8 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Layout.CrossPlatformMeasure at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\91a061fa0393bff02b6fb4e2c2b723bc80d35b4c7d6430fbaa7df5e5d793216a\Layout.cs:269,4    C#
    0x49 in Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutViewGroup.OnMeasure at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\5e7bb4cb58960e36127ca053b2d17d075643d7b9cd5f78d3fcc5aaf7338dd01d\LayoutViewGroup.cs:64,4 C#
    0xA in Android.Views.View.n_OnMeasure_II at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net6.0/android-31/mcw/Android.Views.View.cs:18806,4 C#
    0xB in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPII_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:154,5   C#
    0x39 in Java.Interop.NativeMethods.java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_void_method_a    C#
    0x79 in Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:12320,4  C#
    0x21 in Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualVoidMethod at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:46,5    C#
    0x3C in Android.Views.View.Measure at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net6.0/android-31/mcw/Android.Views.View.cs:17585,5   C#
    0x5D in Microsoft.Maui.ViewHandlerExtensions.GetDesiredSizeFromHandler at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\f44e4109387c12ac95457c136b1a9d98770c4d8a0d4e46d8292e17ac198b041e\ViewHandlerExtensions.Android.cs:91,4  C#
    0x3 in Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler<Microsoft.Maui.ILayout,Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutViewGroup>.GetDesiredSize at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\d3ec223c6cb20ec4aede8c74299f4186e4e1eebe53ac652f30e1ebdea893515b\ViewHandlerOfT.Android.cs:18,4  C#
    0x41 in Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.LayoutExtensions.ComputeDesiredSize at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\2ae5b231c725ac3aac7255c54f0005b7d02c4b5f44d7482e234aaea394223493\LayoutExtensions.cs:26,4   C#
    0x4 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.MeasureOverride at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\acee58e3160c6638c809b2507259264e7aa5efe08e2a1b7922848fd5c6386e84\VisualElement.Impl.cs:149,4  C#
    0x3 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IView.Measure at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\acee58e3160c6638c809b2507259264e7aa5efe08e2a1b7922848fd5c6386e84\VisualElement.Impl.cs:142,4 C#
    0x4D in Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.LayoutExtensions.MeasureContent at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\2ae5b231c725ac3aac7255c54f0005b7d02c4b5f44d7482e234aaea394223493\LayoutExtensions.cs:173,5  C#
    0x9 in Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.LayoutExtensions.MeasureContent at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\2ae5b231c725ac3aac7255c54f0005b7d02c4b5f44d7482e234aaea394223493\LayoutExtensions.cs:152,4   C#
    0x3 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ContentPage.Microsoft.Maui.IContentView.CrossPlatformMeasure at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\88ed0d5887aa2379b6534994314ed3e199270609ebd9d0c95cdcbde6c26f77d9\ContentPage.Impl.cs:28,4  C#
    0x49 in Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentViewGroup.OnMeasure at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\d3aa77caebc65cdaabef036dd3ceea451d7591ff5a5bb3c4752c538154ee2e25\ContentViewGroup.cs:63,4   C#
    0xA in Android.Views.View.n_OnMeasure_II at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net6.0/android-31/mcw/Android.Views.View.cs:18806,4 C#
    0xB in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPII_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:154,5   C#
    0x39 in Java.Interop.NativeMethods.java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_void_method_a    C#
    0x79 in Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:12320,4  C#
    0x21 in Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualVoidMethod at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:46,5    C#
    0x3C in Android.Views.View.Measure at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net6.0/android-31/mcw/Android.Views.View.cs:17585,5   C#
    0x17 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility.ShellPageContainer.OnMeasure at C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\SourceServer\ed5d4acc83123cf134abc1f753e05263e68ffb9855a79a25a0d726bfde0910f9\ShellPageContainer.cs:53,5    C#
    0xA in Android.Views.View.n_OnMeasure_II at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net6.0/android-31/mcw/Android.Views.View.cs:18806,4 C#
    0xB in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPII_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:154,5   C#
```

I tried to fix by adding some try/catch logic and doing a null check, but the changes are never saved. I guess this file is generated at runtime or something.

What should I do to fix this issue.

Note:

1. When I connected my Galaxy Fold I noticed this issue
2. I changed to my Galaxy 9 (non-flip/fold) and it worked like 3-4 times.
3. Then it bombed out...

Please help...
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywJ7A.png

Comment: It looks like an issue with DevExpress controls

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting w/a new app, and will add each page one by one... (should take a few hours)

:-)

Comment: You can try testing on other devices to see if the problem occurs.